# Dating and Valentine practice, do only "friends" get valentines too?

Tags: korean-culture, non-verbal-communication

This question has to do with non-verbal cultural communication.

My understanding is that in Korea dating is conducted by girls selecting boys and that the interest is indicated by a gift on Valentine's Day and there is Valentine's Day every month on the 14th, though two Valentine's Day in February and White Day, March 14, are the big ones.

My question is: do girls only give gifts to a genuine romantic interest (one gift) or do they give gifts to every boy they like, with bigger gifts going to the boys they like more? I am interested in the proper behavior both in children (pre-pubescent) and in older adolescents and young adults.

Answer (score 1):

The latter one.

It is not rare that some people give small gifts to every person(opposite sex) in their community (office, class).

I'm early 30s, so not sure for case in children and older adolescents these days.

Comment: In my early 20s, we did that. Not always, but quite often to "hide" the person that you *actually* like.